# Erro ao retornar HashMap para o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, hashmap

No momento de retornar o hashmap para o javascript obtive o seguinte erro:

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating
>   responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request
>   "accept" headers.

Chamada da função validamesa() do javascript:

```
    <div data-role="controlgroup">
        <label for="txtMesa">Informe a mesa de origem:</label>
        <input type="text" name="codigo" id="txtMesa" maxlength="3" onchange="validamesa()"/>
    </div>
```

Função validamesa no arquivo js:

```
function validamesa(){
    var mesa = document.getElementById("txtMesa").value;

    if (mesa != null || mesa != "")
    {
        $.ajax( {
            type : "GET",
            url : "validarMesa.do?mesa="+mesa,
            success : function(data) {
                if (data.mensagem != "OK"){ 
                    alert(data.mensagem);
                    document.getElementById("txtMesa").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("txtMesa").focus();
                }
            }
            error : function(msg) {
                                console.log(msg.responseText);
                alert("Erro:"+msg.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Agora o @RequestMapping do Spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping("/validarMesa.do")
public @ResponseBody 
Map<String, ? extends Object> validarMesa(BigDecimal mesa,
        HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse resp) {
    Map<String, Object> modelMap = null;
    Tab_MesasDao oMesaDao = null;

    try {
        oMesaDao = new Tab_MesasDao();
        if (oMesaDao.validar_Mesa(mesa)) {
            modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
            modelMap.put("mensagem", "OK");
            resp.setStatus(200);
        } else {
            modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
            modelMap.put("mensagem", "ERRO!" + oMesaDao.getMensagem());
            resp.setStatus(200);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        modelMap.put("mensagem", "ERRO!" + ex.getMessage());
        resp.setStatus(404);

    } finally {
        oMesaDao = null;
    }

    return modelMap;
}
```

Estou com esse problema a alguns dias já e não encontrei nenhum fórum que me ajudasse. Alguém já teve esse problema? Estou começando agora com o JavaWeb.

Comment: O problema parece simples: sua requisição AJAX não diz qual o tipo de retorno que ela espera no cabeçalho `Accept` e da mesma forma você não especifica no método qual o tipo de retorno. Como o Java vai adivinhar que você quer JSON e não XML, por exemplo? Você precisa ou definir o tipo no método ou usar o atributo `accepts` na chamada AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acredito que você está retornando um JSON dessa action do seu controller, sendo assim o Spring utiliza o Jackson para serializar seu objeto para o formato JSON, porem o mesmo tem que estar configurado na sua aplicaçõo se sua aplicação usa o maven seria algo tão simples quanto adicionar o Jackson as suas dependências, algo do tipo:

```
<dependencies>
...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Agora caso você não use nenhuma ferramenta para gerenciar suas dependências você teria baixar o jar do Jackson e adiciona-lo no classpath da sua aplicação, caso esse seja o seu caso segue o link onde você pode baixar o mesmo.

### http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload

-- Referencias

### http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

### https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Beleza Leonardo, apenas baixar o jar do Jackson e adicioná-lo ao meu projeto já resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom Matheus, :)